# changing css class on the basis of list size

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a list, let say size of the list is 5:

```
<ul> 
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

In the css I have three classes:

```
1 - li:first-child
2 - li:-nth-child(3)
3 - li:last-child
```

Ok the problem start here if the list size in 1
it implement fist child and last child class on that same element.
i's that any way to stop loading the last child class? 
I hope I have made my self clear.

Comment: Try declaring the css for first-child after the last-child declaration.

Comment: There are `:not()` selector but only for moder browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring the css for first-child after the last-child declaration.

In the case below the text 'List item' should be displayed in bold.

```
ul li:last-child {
 font-weight:normal;
}

ul li:first-child {
 font-weight:bold;
}

<ul>
 <li>List item</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: It works! thanks. now a follow up question: - if there is only one element in list. but i want to implement li:-nth-child(3) on that(because there is whole bunch of tages encsloed with nth(3) element n i wnat to those one to be pick up) , can i control it by css or i have to go to java script? I am new in css and java script so if it seems stupid , i apologis for that.

Comment: I think you would probably have to use javascript for that.